# Python, github search regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I prepared a regular expresion in Python that searches for github webpage:

```
github = re.findall(
    "https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?github\.com\/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\/?", 
text)
```

But now it searches for links that starts with https. How this could be modified, so the regex would search for strings that start either with **https** or just with **www** ?

Now my regex will find this:

```
https://github.com/helloman
```

as well as this:

```
https://www.github.com/helloman
```

but not this:

```
www.github.com/helloman
```

How it can be changed to accept all three options?

Comment: The question isn't clear for me. Can you post some example URLs?

Comment: edited, hope its better now

Comment: I tested your regex with all tree examples and it already does what you want. Can't see what is wrong. Can you clarify?

Comment: I am pretty sure it does't work for address like `www.github.com/XXX`

Comment: So, you want to find URLs that start either with `www.` _or_ `https?://(?:www\.)?`. You can use the OR syntax to do that: `(thing)|(another thing)`. Or gather _all URLs_ with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) and then use a URL parser (I think one is provided by `urllib`) to check the domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
(?:https?://)?(?:www[.])?github[.]com/[\w-]+/?
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> github=re.compile('(?:https?://)?(?:www[.])?github[.]com/[\w-]+/?')
>>> github.findall('www.github.com/accdias/dotfiles.git')
['www.github.com/accdias/']
>>> github.findall('github.com/accdias/dotfiles.git')
['github.com/accdias/']
>>> github.findall('https://github.com/accdias/dotfiles.git')
['https://github.com/accdias/']
>>> github.findall('http://github.com/accdias/dotfiles.git')
['http://github.com/accdias/']
>>> github.findall('http://www.github.com/accdias/dotfiles.git')
['http://www.github.com/accdias/']
>>> github.findall('https://www.github.com/accdias/dotfiles.git')
['https://www.github.com/accdias/']
>>>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: `github.findall('www.github.com/accdias/dotfiles.git') == []`, but the OP wants a regex that _does accept_ this URL

Comment: Oh! Now I see. Thanks for clarifying. I was under the impression OP wanted to *exclude* those without the protocol.

Comment: IMHO `//` is clearer than `/{2}` and you've missed the hyphen, OP said `[A-Za-z0-9_-]+` that is `[\w-]+`, not `\w+` alone.

Comment: @Toto, indeed. I will update the answer. Thanks for bringing that up.

Answer (score 0):

You are only missing a couple of brackets.

https://regex101.com/r/NEuD5f/2

```
(https:\/\/)?(www\.)?github\.com\/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\/?
```

P.S.

It will now match `github.com/xxx` too. I'm not sure that is what you want.

Comment: now i get `[('', 'www.')]` from text that i use